# Font installation in TeXShop on a Mac

Tags: fonts, mac, texshop

I apologize for this being an extremely naive question, but I just can't seem to wrap my head around what the sources I've consulted so far are saying.

I'm writing a Beamer presentation in TeXShop, on a Mac running Lion. I've download some Optima fonts from CTAN at http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/urw/classico/ and would like to install them on my distribution, and then to use them in my document.

Can anyone help a fellow TeXer out with a simple, step-by-step guide of what to do here, from installing, to the appropriate command line to paste into my TeX document?

One confusing point is that I cannot seem to locate my texmf folder. If I go to ~/Library/texlive/2011, all I see there is something called temxf-var.

Many thanks ahead of time to anyone kind enough to take this on.

Comment: The path to the `texmf` folder is `~/Library/texmf`

Comment: Of all the questions, ones about installing fonts are the *least* naive!  Standard TeX font installation is the closest thing to a dark art there is.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is generally better to install fonts in your system-wide `texmf-local` folder rather than your personal `texmf` folder.   In fact, TeXLive now has a simple script installed for installing the non-free fonts such as classico.

**The really simple way**

Open a Terminal window and type the following: (you should be logged in to an account with administrator privileges.)

```
sudo getnonfreefonts-sys classico
```

And you are done!

To use the font, add

```
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{uop}
```

to your document preamble to make Classico the sans serif default.

**What the script is doing (the slightly more complicated way)**

Effectively the script is simply downloading the font from CTAN and executing 3 commands.  Here's a step by step version of what it does, which you can also do if you prefer. I also leave it in for fonts that are *not* installed by the script.   I will begin from the assumption that you have downloaded the `uop.zip` file and it is in `~/Downloads`.

Open a Terminal window and type the following:

```
sudo unzip ~/Downloads/uop.zip -d /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local
```

You will be asked for your password.

This should return the a whole bunch of lines reporting the unzipped files:

> ```
> Archive:  uop.zip
>   inflating: /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/doc/fonts/urw/Public.htm  
>   inflating: /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/doc/fonts/urw/classico.txt  
>    creating: /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/type1/urw/optima/
>   inflating: /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/type1/urw/optima/uopb8a.pfb  
>   inflating: /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/type1/urw/optima/uopbi8a.pfb
>
>   ... (lines deleted)   
>
>    creating: /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/uop/
>   inflating: /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/uop/8ruop.fd  
>   inflating: /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/uop/ot1uop.fd  
>   inflating: /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/uop/t1uop.fd  
>   inflating: /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/uop/ts1uop.fd
> ```

Next enter

```
sudo texhash
```

this will rebuild the file list database to reflect the added files. This command should return:

> ```
> texhash: Updating /usr/local/texlive/2011/../texmf-local/ls-R... 
> texhash: Updating /usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf/ls-R... 
> texhash: Updating /usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-config/ls-R... 
> texhash: Updating /usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/ls-R... 
> texhash: Updating /usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-var/ls-R... 
> texhash: Done.
> ```

Next enter

```
sudo updmap-sys --enable Map=uop.map
```

This command will enable the font map files and produce a lot of output too:

> ```
> Config file: "/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg"
> dvips output dir: "/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-var/fonts/map/dvips/updmap"
> pdftex output dir: "/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap"
> dvipdfm output dir: "/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-var/fonts/map/dvipdfm/updmap"
> pxdvi output dir: "/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-var/fonts/map/pxdvi/updmap"
>
> /usr/texbin/updmap is creating new map files
> using the following configuration:
>   LW35 font names                  : URWkb
>   prefer outlines                  : true
>   texhash enabled                  : true
>   download standard fonts (dvips)  : true
>   download standard fonts (pdftex) : true
>   kanjiEmbed/variant replacement   : noEmbed/
>   create a mapfile for pxdvi       : false
>
> Scanning for LW35 support files  [  3 files]
> Scanning for MixedMap entries    [ 44 files]
> Scanning for KanjiMap entries    [  5 files]
> Scanning for Map entries         [169 files]
>
> Generating output for dvipdfm...
> Generating output for ps2pk...
> Generating output for dvips...
> Generating output for pdftex...
>
> Files generated:
>   /usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-var/fonts/map/dvips/updmap:
>        11499 2012-03-27 23:01:54 builtin35.map
>        15962 2012-03-27 23:01:54 download35.map
>       586252 2012-03-27 23:01:55 psfonts_pk.map
>       847257 2012-03-27 23:01:55 psfonts_t1.map
>       842824 2012-03-27 23:01:54 ps2pk.map
>           14 2012-03-27 23:01:56 psfonts.map -> psfonts_t1.map
>   /usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap:
>       842831 2012-03-27 23:01:56 pdftex_dl14.map
>       841257 2012-03-27 23:01:55 pdftex_ndl14.map
>           15 2012-03-27 23:01:56 pdftex.map -> pdftex_dl14.map
>   /usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-var/fonts/map/dvipdfm/updmap:
>         5003 2012-03-27 23:01:54 kanjix.map
>
> Transcript written on "/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-var/web2c/updmap.log".
> /usr/texbin/updmap: Updating ls-R files.
> ```

Now you are done.  Use as above.

Comment: Excuse me, but the manual installation process that you're describing shouldn't be done only after dropping the respective files inside (the subfolders of) the 'font' and 'tex' folders (as in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88423/manual-font-installation)? It seems that the first command in the second part of the answer simply decompress the file and put it into texmf-local instead of placing them properly in the respective folders (as described in the answer that I cited).

Comment: @user40276 No, the command as written is correct. The files are zipped with their correct directory structure, and they will expand into the correct folders automatically.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this through Tex Live Utility (a GUI). Unlike the previous answer on this question, here's how you actually do it (on mac):

1. Fire up Tex Live Utility
2. On the search box at the top on the right-hand side, type whatever font you want to install e.g. 'fontin'
3. It will (hopefully) display the font as "uninstalled" under 'Status'
4. Right-click on the package search result and click 'install'

That should be it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also install the [TeX Live Utility](http://amaxwell.github.io/tlutility/) GUI, which lets you easily install fonts with a single click, etc

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: More explanation is required.