# Font installation woes - TeXShop on a Mac

Tags: fonts, installing

Have read (carefully, I hope) the earlier question [Font installation in TeXShop on a Mac](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/49736/2693-) looked to be exactly what I needed. Also looked at http://www.tug.org/fonts/fontinstall.html#fndb

Am trying to install Arial from CTAN.

However, the `sudo` commands `getnonfreefonts`, `texhash` and `updmap` did not seem to be available on my system. So I have downloaded and installed MacTeX 2012 (previously had 2010), which enabled `texhash` and `updmap`, but not `getnonfreefonts`, and tried again.

The unzipped files went into /usr/local/texlive/2012/../texmf-local/arial which I think is right.

sudo texhash made all the right noises, as in the answer to the earlier question referred to above.

`sudo updmap-sys --enable Map=ua1.map` produced a limited response. I had made earlier attempts, sometimes with the wrong map name. The font is not 'working'. `testfont` confirms this, saying that `ua1b8a` (one of the `.tfm` files) cannot be found.

I have clearly 'screwed up' my system somewhere along the line, unless I have misunderstood something. What do I do now? Remove all traces of TeX... from my computer and start again? Or...

Sorry to be so dumb.

Comment: I have the similar problem and tried to install the getnonfreefonts. But my Mac doesn't know the command texlua. Really I tried it the whole day and stuck for this shit. Can you please help me?

Answer (score 2):

Don't be dramatic! ;-) If the distribution didn't install `getnonfreefonts` you can install it yourself and it will do his magic in a few steps.

### Download getnonfreefonts

Get the program at http://www.tug.org/fonts/getnonfreefonts/ and follow the very simple instructions on the very page I pointed. Assuming you installed the Tex Live distro system-wide, you may want to modify the commands in

```
sudo env PATH=$PATH texlua install-getnonfreefonts
```

assuming also that your PATH points to the Tex Live binaries (which should be).

### Install arial-urw

You should be fine with

```
sudo getnonfreefonts arial-urw
```

and voila! Font installed. :-)

Comment: Many thanks. I was dumb, but now all sorted. LaTeX fonts unlocked!

Answer (score 1):

Install the [TeX Live Utility](http://code.google.com/p/mactlmgr/) GUI, which lets you easily install fonts with a single click, etc