# Texlua not be recognized

Tags: fonts, installing, mactex

I have the exactly same problem like in the question [Font installation woes - TeXShop on a Mac](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84533/font-installation-woes-texshop-on-a-mac/98997#98997):
I'd like to install the `nonfreefonts` package, but I can not do the command `texlua`. My terminal says "command not found".
I have also MacTeX 2012 installed and I really need Arial for my Bachelor Thesis.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: are you sure that the binaries of TeX are in your search path? Test it in a terminal with `texlua -v`

Comment: No command not found. So how can I add them to my path?

Comment: okay sorry. fixed it by myself. this command did it: PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2012/bin/x86_64-darwin:$PATH .. thanks for the Hint!