# Font works with \usepackage but not with \newfontfamily

Tags: fonts, fontspec, ebgaramond, installing-fonts

I am trying to get someone else's thesis template to run, but the EBGaramond font is not working. I also have never used .cls files in latex, so I'm not sure if I'm missing something. In the .cls file, the line causing problems is:

`\newfontfamily{\smallcaps}[RawFeature={+c2sc,+scmp}]{EB Garamond}`

and the error is: *Package fontspec Error: the font ''EB Garamond'' cannot be found*

I have tried replacing "EB Garamond" with "ebgaramond" and "EBGaramond".
I followed [these directions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49736/font-installation-in-texshop-on-a-mac) to make sure the font was installed. To check that it was working, I tried using the command `\usepackage{ebgaramond}` in another document, which worked fine, so there seems to be something wrong about the specific line above. Also, I'm not sure if this is relevant, but the previous user of this template was exclusively using Overleaf.

Comment: are you using xelatex or luatex

Comment: I've tried both, and I get the same error either way

Comment: you have provided no test file so hard to debug but are you sure you have the font installed? I'd expect it to be at a location such as `/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/ebgaramond/EBGaramond-Regular.otf`

Comment: Yes, it was in the location you specified (though with 2020 instead of 2021). I'm not exactly sure how to put together a text file in this case, but if it's necessary I can try to figure that out.

Comment: xelatex will not find it by name unless you have configured fontcongig to find it so you could try replacing `EB Garamond` by `EBGaramond-Regular.otf` so the file can be fond by lpathsearch rather than fontconfig (luatex shoud work the same way with either form)

Comment: Wow that seems to have worked! Can you give instructions on how to configure fontcongig to find it so that I can avoid having to change "EB Garamond" to "EBGaramond-Regular.otf"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

xelatex will not find fonts in the tex-live tree by name unless you have configured fontconfig to find them, so you could try replacing the internal font name `EB Garamond` by the file name `EBGaramond-Regular.otf` so the file can be found by kpathsearch rather than fontconfig (luatex should work the same way with either form).

To configure fontconfig you need a file such as

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
  <dir>/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype</dir>
  <dir>/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/truetype</dir>
</fontconfig>
```

"somewhere" (Mine is called `local.conf` in `/etc/fonts` but the details on a Mac will be different).  Then run `fc-cache` to rebuild its font cache.

See `texdoc texlive`

> Section 3.4.4 System font conﬁguration for XeTeX and LuaTeX

Comment: For Mac the directory is `/usr/local/etc/fonts/conf.d`